# Side of TableViewCell gets cut off when applying a gradient mask

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, gradient, mask

My tableView sits within a blank content view with constraints holding it in place. The table will function properly in the container by itself, but as soon as I apply a gradient using the code below, the gradient works perfectly, except the right hand side of my tableViewCells get cut off. It only happens when the gradient is applied. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Before Gradient is added, table view looks like this:

[TableView with full TableViewCells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNmL.png)

After the gradient is added, the table view looks like this:

[TableView with cut TableViewCells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxtAa.png)

This is the code I am using to apply the gradient.

```
        let gradientLayerMask = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayerMask.frame = gradientMask.bounds
    gradientLayerMask.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayerMask.locations = [0.0,0.1,0.9,1.0]

    gradientMask.layer.mask = gradientLayerMask

    exerciseTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: What is the gradient intended to do? I see no gradient effect. Evidently you are just masking out the right side of the table.

Comment: @matt The gradient is intended to fade the top and bottom of the table view so it looks smoother when scrolling instead of being a solid line that everything disappears at.

Comment: Well I don’t see it doing that. In any case clearly it’s width is less than the width of the table view.

Comment: @matt I adjusted vertical inset so that when the tableview is not being scrolled, the gradient is not visible, so the gradient itself would not be visible until scrolled. I agree with what you are saying about it being more narrow than the tableview itself, however at no point in the code have I changed the size programmatically. I've gone through re done all my constraints to make sure those were correct as well. That said, I will continue to look to see if I accidentally changed sizes elsewhere.

Comment: But you didn’t show where your code was. If `viewDidLoad` that is too early.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put some delay for gradient code

```
func delay(time: Double, closure:
    @escaping ()->()) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time) {
        closure()
    }

}
```

Use this way.

```
delay(time: 0.2) {
    //gradient code
}
```

I hope it's work for you.

Comment: I will give this a try. Might I ask why this would have an effect? Is there some animation timing affecting the display that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Whenever you design UI in small device size like iPhone 5 SE and you run on big device like iPhone 6 then UI will take some time to get original frame, so here you need to put some delay for gradient related UI change.

Comment: It worked! I was not aware of that, thank you for letting me know. It's strange because I was designing this on the iPhone X in IB, but running on an iPhone XR Simulator. Very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The right way is to put the code in the right place.